# QStackedLayout in Qt Designer

Tags: qt, qt5, qstackedwidget

I can use a `QStackedWidget` fine in Qt Creator, but it has buttons that allow the user to change the current page. I only want to do that programmatically. Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a Stacked Layout anywhere in the form editor. Is there any way I can use a `QStackedLayout` in Qt Designer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Oh so actually the buttons of a `QStackedWidget` are apparently only shown in design mode, so you can just use a `QStackedWidget`. I thought they'd still be in the program because they also there when you preview the form, but I guess the form preview uses the same engine as the form designer.